# += operator cannot be applied to operands of type 'int' and 'object'

Tags: c#, for-loop, operators

Visual studio 2012 is outputing the indicated compiler error message when I attempt to compile the following code:

```
        string choice;
        var inputs = new ArrayList();

        do
        {
            Console.Write("enter a score:");
            int score = Int32.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
            inputs.Add(score);

            Console.WriteLine("do you want to enter more scores? y for yes and n for no");
            choice = Console.ReadLine();
            if (choice == "n") { break; }

            while (choice != "y" && choice != "n")
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Please enter a valid response!");
                choice = Console.ReadLine();
            }

        }
        while (choice == "y");


        int sum = 0;
        for (int i = 0; i < inputs.Count; i++)
        {
            sum += inputs[i];
        }
```

compiler error: `Operator += cannot be applied to operands of type 'int' and 'object'`

However, if I compile the following I get no such error message:

```
 int[] arr = new int[] { 1, 2, 3 };
        int sum = 0;
        for (int i = 0; i < arr.Length; i++)
        {
            sum += arr[i];
        }
```

Comment: Because `ArrayList` is untyped (and generally shouldn't be used since introduction of generics). And you can't add any `object` to `int`, naturally.

Comment: `var inputs = new List<int>();`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you use [`ArrayList`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/system.collections.arraylist), the type of `inputs[i]` is `Object`. The compiler is telling you (quite appropriately) that it can't use `+=` when you're using `int` and `Object`.

In your second example, of course, you're using an `int[]`, so there's no problem.

You could probably use a cast to get around this, but I would use [`List`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/6sh2ey19%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) with an `int` type parameter instead:

```
var inputs = List<int>();
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to supply a type to your `ArrayList`. Like so: `var inputs = new List<int>();`

Without explicitly stating which kind of objects you want to store in your list, the compiler will treat it as a `List<object>`.

Answer (score 0):

`ArrayList` is an untyped list of objects. Objects you add `to` such collection don't need to be homogeneous (it can hold few `int`, few `float`, few strings and one `Cat`). you have to cast object you extract to their proper type (of course because compiler doesn't know how to add `int` with `object` unless you're using `dynamic`):

```
for (int i = 0; i < arr.Length; i++)
{
    sum += (int)inputs [i];
}
```

That said I'd suggest to use a strongly typed list (for example `List<T>`) instead of `ArrayList`, like this:

```
var inputs = new List<int>();
```

Why? Because with `ArrayList` nothing stops you to write (on purpose or because of a bug) this code:

```
inputs.Add(123);
inputs.Add("123");
inputs.Add(new Version("1.0"));
```

Obviously this will fail at run-time when wrong object type will be added to your list, this constraint (list of integers) is known at compile-time so it's much better to enforce it. Moreover you'll avoid a cast but performance gain is so small that it'll go unnoticed for sure.

Answer (score 0):

inputs is an ArrayList, which means it contains objects. You need to cast to int:

```
(int)inputs[i];
```

But why not use a `List<int>` instead? ArrayList is a leftover from C# 1.0 No one wants to use that

Answer (score 0):

An Arraylist is always only known to be a list of `object` - in this case it is indeed an integer - but this is not know at run-time.

There are two ways to solve this:

the best, would be to change your ArrayList to use generics (recommended):

```
var inputs = new List<int>();
```

or, cast at the point of usage:

```
sum += (int)inputs[i];
```

Answer (score -1):

This is because `inputs` is an `ArrayList`:

```
var inputs = new ArrayList();
```

The compiler doesn't know about the type of the array item since array list is not typed

You would need to convert the element to an `int` or just use a `List<int>` which is preferable IMO:

```
int sum = 0;
for (int i = 0; i < inputs.Count; i++)
{
    sum += (int)inputs[i];
}
```